# How to Change The ViewPagerIndicator's Animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have created an app with the `ViewPager` Library with three fragments and it works fine But my question here is that how can i change the animation of the `ViewPager`?

Like this Animation:

[image]

You can see That it nicely animate it like a cube!!
So any Help?

Thanks in advance :) !!

Comment: I would assume this would be handled [via `setPageTransformer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setPageTransformer(boolean,%20android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.PageTransformer)), though I have never tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to supply your `ViewPager` with a [PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html).

Create a class which implements `PageTransformer` and override `transformPage()` according to your desired animation.

```
public class CustomPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

    }
}
```

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

pager.setPageTransformer(true, new CustomPageTransformer());
```

You can find a couple of examples [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html).

Answer (score 2):

Check Jazzy View Pager, it implements cubes transitions you are looking for:

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager

Just replace your standard view pager with `com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager.JazzyViewPager` (probably in your layout XML file). Then use the `setTransitionEffect` to one of the values defined in the `TransitionEffect`enumeration.

```
pager.setTransitionEffect(TransitionEffect.CubeIn);
```

You'll also have to give the pager a reference to managed items by calling the `setObjectForPosition` method while instantiating your pages :

```
pager.setObjectForPosition(subactivity, position);
```

Transition effects currently available are : 
        Standard,
        Tablet,
        CubeIn,
        CubeOut,
        Flip,
        Stack,
        ZoomIn,
        ZoomOut,
        RotateUp,
        RotateDown,
        and Accordion.

Comment: can you please get me a full example of jazzy view pager with the relevant code? I've asked a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092999/android-example-of-jazzy-view-pager-with-tabs-implementation